# Getting UEFI shell when trying to boot OS X in Virtual Box

Tags: linux, macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am using the latest [test build](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds) of Virtual Box (normal versions don't work on El Capitan).

When trying to boot a Virtual Machine with an El Capitan cdr file ([created from the command line](https://gist.github.com/x11xyz/8928a4f01cf9df94ccb9)) I end up getting the UEFI shell instead of the OS X installer.

[image]

How would I be able to boot the El Capitan cdr file? I am also running El Capitan as the host too.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1235970 might help

Answer (score 8):

1. Type *exit* at the UEFI Shell Prompt
2. Go to **Boot Maintenance Manager**
3. Choose **Boot From File**
4. Go to **Preboot....**
5. Navigate through **[Some GUID] -> System -> Library -> CoreServices**
6. Finally select **boot.efi**

Your machine should now boot up. Works for me for Big Sur.

Comment: Note after step 6 you have to wait a lot and see lots of scrolling text before system starts to boot.

Answer (score 5):

You have to disable EFI boot in the machine settings. Then it will work, however, you will have to have Chameleon installed on the .cdr image.

Comment: Why the downvote? At least say what's wrong with my answer...

Comment: For some toxic reason, the SE community sometimes downvote answers automatically if your rep looks too low. yep, hen-and-egg

Comment: This solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

This is not working in VirtualBox at the time of writing (2015-10-07).

Apple migrated the format of the partition table for El Capitan boot image from MBR to GPT and VirtualBox does not yet support HFS+ filesystems on GPT partitioned drives when starting from EFI.

Refer to this issue:

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14490

Answer (score -3):

The easiest way to not get this error is to use **VMware Workstation Pro**.

Even if you prefer VirtualBox, if you even more prefer to do things the easy way, install VMware Workstation Pro.

You can install it [here](https://my.vmware.com/en/web/vmware/info/slug/desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation_pro/14_0).

I have not tried this method myself, so I cannot guarantee that it will work.

Thanks for taking your time to listen,

Zyrom121

Comment: If you haven't tried it and aren't sure it works, how can you say it's the easiest solution?

Comment: Because I have tried it on an older version of VMware.