# Does audio work in Oracle Virtualbox when macOS is the guest OS?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, audio

I created a virtualbox vm for macOS High Sierra on two host OSs, macOS Catalina (as explained at [How can I install a macOS VM Guest under VirtualBox on a Mac host?](https://superuser.com/questions/1351460/how-can-i-install-a-macos-vm-guest-under-virtualbox-on-a-mac-host/1530695#1530695)) and Windows 10. In both cases the audio doesn't work. Audio is enabled in the VM settings but I can't hear any sound in the High Sierra guest. In the sound preferences in MacOS the "muted" checkbox -in the "audio output volume" section- is checked, and grayed out.
Do you know if audio is expected to work in virtualbox when macOS is the guest OS?

Comment: For Catalina, make sure you're on VB 6.1.4, lots of people have been having issues since Catalina, but I don't have any detailed fixes as I use Parallels. macOS on Win host is off-topic here, however, as it's unlicensed.

Comment: Yes, the VB version is 6.1.4.r136177. So, when creating the VM on Mjave the audio is supposed to be functional?

Comment: Well, as the hardware is Apple, the drivers should already be present & correct. idk how VB goes about 'additions' for macOS, because none actually exist for VB officially. As it's unlicensed other than on a Mac it shouldn't be necessary, but I really am not certain how it works. As I say, I use Parallels which doesn't have these issues at all - their additions are fully licensed. VB's aren't.

Comment: I recently set up a Mojave VM in virtualbox and I recall them insisting that you turn off audio support in vbox as it doesn't work. Just wish I remembered where I saw it...