# MacOS X Catalina VM froze on boot

Tags: macos, boot, virtualbox, virtual-machine, macos-catalina

I am attempting to set up a MacOS X Catalina  virtual machine on VirtualBox 6.1.16 r140961 (Qt5.6.2).
I followed the guide at [WikiGain](https://www.wikigain.com/install-macos-catalina-on-virtualbox-on-windows-vmdk/) and loaded into a UEFI interactive shell. I found a user in the comments with the same problem and a link to a solution. I followed the link to a [SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1351435/1260302) and followed the instructions to boot the *boot.efi* file. I saw a bunch of white text scroll past, as is expected in the WikiGain article. Then the screen froze, and I saw a bunch of lines containing the string `Err(0xe)`.

This is my 4th time attempting to set up a Mac VM on my computer with different tutorials and a similar error. I am able to sucessfully run Windows and Linux VMs, but not Mac. Virtualization is enabled in my BIOS. I only need this VM to run as a server, so I do not need sound or a normal display size.

Links to images showing the problem:

- [VirtualBox Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpVPS.png)
- [Error Message on Boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnKtF.png)
- [System Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BDro.png)
- VM Settings: [System>Motherboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnFTS.png) [System>Processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac5mp.png) [Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo9ZC.png)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the use of macOS on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Comment: @Tetsujin I disagree. The provided link is about Hackintosh's, but this question is about virtual OS X. If I had no original Mac hardware, it may be against the apple EULA when downloading the software. If, for example, I purchased a second-hand Mac Mini and used its license key, would that be allowed? If someone asked a question in that situation with the same issue as me, would that be okay, considering that someone without a Mac key could follow the same instructions? In any case, Apple has not and likley will not crack down on this usage of their software.

Comment: The "license key" for macOS is Apple hardware. The OS has no purchase price & no installer/validity key, your 'entry token' is your purchased hardware. IMO, that differentiation alone makes it the same as asking for a Windows keygen. Legalities aside, trying to do this in totally unsupported hardware with no available drivers is fraught with user-specific difficulty, which no-one except an owner of identical hardware could even help you investigate. Further - opinion aside, the owners of Stack Exchange have decided they don't want to play in these muddied waters, so have deemed it off-topic.

Comment: @Tetsujin That makes sense. However, there are other questions on SuperUser like the one I linked that discuss this same topic, and the users reached a consensus that it is allowed. Also, the question you linked is 10 years old. [There is a new question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12050/revisit-the-hackintosh-policy) revisiting this policy, and most users agree to lift the ban. I notice that you disagreed with this in the chatroom, but that is an opinion.

Comment: This is one of those areas where user consensus was overridden by management policy. Again, legality aside, you have a one-person problem, unsolvable by anyone familiar with Macs & VMs in general. The lead answer on your linked question explains this. So it boils down to "even if it doesn't get closed, the chances of a working answer are slim". Ultimately it's not up to me, it takes 5 user close votes or a mod vote to close any question

Comment: I understand. If this question is voted to be closed, then that is fair. If there is a chance of a working answer, I would like to try.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix! In one [Virtualbox Forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=85631#p407278) a user suggests to run the command
`VBoxManage modifyvm "High Sierra" --cpu-profile "Intel Core i7-6700K"`

I replaced High Sierra with my VM name and the VM booted to the installation after seecting the boot.efi file! It took a long time, but I now have a working Mac VM! =)